# Why fetchDashboard function is being called multiple times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm building a React app with Redux, below `fetchDashboard` is a action of Redux. It is being called in multiple time like if we click it for first time it will be called 1 times then if we click it for 2 time it will get called 2 times and so on.

```
var [category, setcategory] = useState("header");
useEffect(() => {
function toggleCategory(e) {
  var cate = this.text.toLowerCase();
  setcategory(cate);
  fetchDashboard(category); 
}
var anchor = document.querySelectorAll("a");
anchor.forEach((a) => a.addEventListener("click", toggleCategory));
anchor.forEach(a =>
  a.text.toLowerCase() === category
    ? a.classList.add("active")
    : a.classList.remove("active")
);
},[category]);
```

My return function:

```
     <>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li className="logo">
            <a href="/">Tempo</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a>Header</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a>Navbar</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a>Section</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a>Inline</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a>Aside</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </>
```

It has used `cancelBubble` and `stopPropagation`, but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the reason is because every single time, once you click on an anchor tag, it will attach again the `toggleCategory` function because of `category` in dependency array. If the `category` value is changing `useEffect` hook's callback will be triggered again.

One possible way is to separate the `addEventListener` calls into a different `useEffect` hook where you might have an empty or different dependency array.

The solution can be change like the following:

```
const toggleCategory = useCallback(e => {
  // removed line which has the mentioned issue down below in +1:
  // var cate = this.text.toLowerCase();
  setcategory(cate);
  fetchDashboard(category);
// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}, []);

useEffect(() => {    
  const anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a');
  anchors.forEach((a) => {
    a.addEventListener('click', toggleCategory);
  });
}, [toggleCategory]);

useEffect(() => {
  const anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a');
  anchors.forEach(a =>
    a.text.toLowerCase() === category
      ? a.classList.add('active')
      : a.classList.remove('active')
  );
}, [category]);
```

For `toggleCategory` it is suggested to use [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) hook:

> `useCallback` will return a memoized version of the callback that only changes if one of the dependencies has changed.

**+1 suggestion:**

In functional components there is no `this` as you use in your code even if I don't have the whole context of that line: `var cate = this.text.toLowerCase();`. Maybe it is worth to take a look at that as well.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

=>Remove the useEffect dependency 'catagory'  and make it as '[]' so that effect will run only once when the component is mounted.

=>As per my understanding, in your case, useEffect runs once when component is mounted, and it changes 'catagory'. As 'catagory' is made as depedency of useEffect, effect gonna run again.And second time, there is no change in 'catagory' value, effect does not run there after.